# Do Wireless Speakers Have Poor Sound?

Tags: speakers

I searched for wireless speakers which work with PC and Mac, and came across some articles. I read that wireless speakers are poor sound. Is that correct?

Why would wireless speakers be any different from wired ones with sound quality?

Answer (score 5):

The reason wireless speakers are said to have such poor quality sound is because the audio is usually transmitted in an analog fashion, which means that other devices can interfere with it easily.

With speakers that use a digital form of transmission such as Bluetooth you have more resistance to interference, but in the rare occasions where there is enough interference, instead of distorting the sound it will be cut out completely.

Also note that all wireless speakers generate interference of their own which can interfere with other wireless devices.

Comment: Some good info. +1

Comment: Thanks for your informations, how can I plug easily a pc (or mac) with wires on a speaker ? My problem is I don't want many wire in my apartment (it's not beautiful ;) )

Comment: @Kiva: Not one bit of my answer said "don't use wireless speakers".